# dsconfigad - Responding to terminal question

Tags: applescript, script

I am "very" new to making scripts, so please be patient with me.

I am using Meraki console on where I work and im trying to create a script for the apple devices to join out active directory to put on Meraki

Apple OS Version: Catalina

Sorry if my script is short, its because I work in a school and need to keep things slightly confidential, but here is my script setup so far, which it works

```
dsconfigad -add "[Active Direcory]"

dsconfigad -groups "[Active Direcory Group]" -force
```

---

If there already an existing account the terminal responds
"Computer account already exists! Bind to exisitng? (y/n)"

Then I have to manually press the 'y' button and the 'return' button

Question: Is there a way in the script to make the script press 'y' and 'return' button to respond back to the terminal?

I need something like:

```
If terminal display "Computer account already exists! Bind to existing? (y/n)"
    tell application "terminal"
    keystroke 'y' + 'return'
```

Comment: Does adding `-force` to the `dsconfigad` command solve it?